# Android: (Google Maps) Disable Picture-in-picture Mode Via Intent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, picture-in-picture

Is there a way to disable the picture-in-picture mode  for Google Maps via intent options? In my use-case this mode is useless and I want to avoid using it.

On devices running Android 8.0 or higher, picture-in-picture is enabled by default. Also I don't want to have the user disable this setting. The best solution would be to override this settings.

If someone found a way to achieve this and is able to share the code, would be appreciated.